# Is it possible to transfer data from Python to HTML template/Website (Using Flask)

Tags: python, html, variables, flask, webserver

I am a noob to this topic and this is my first question here.
I want to ask if it is possible to *upload a changing variable* *from python to an HTML* textbox/paragraph/forms? 
I've seen several methods but can't figure out a one which work.
I'm using *Python 3.4 on my raspberry PI 2* from which I will be also hosting a web server *using flask*.
I would preferabbly use flask too for this task too but anyways if it's not possible I can use any other methods as soon as they are easier.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: you need to clarify your question AND get more information about how flask/jinja2 work. From your question, I am not sure if you are talking about some kind of AJAX interaction or about rendering to a template.

Comment: Either render the template to contain all the data on flask so that the client gets everything at once, or include a script which makes an AJAX request to flask for the data. Those are your main options.

Comment: You can definitely post a) different form data (or, different variable names) to the same flask endpoint, and b) forms with different data (same name, with different data). You can *also* have flask render variables using Jinja, which produces the HTML that you return to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite confusing though, but from what i understood you can do it like this

in python file:

```
    from flask import Flask,render_template
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        name='stackoverflow'
        return render_template('index.html', name=name)
```

and in index.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script>
        var name = {{ name|safe }}
    </script>
    <h2> this is passed from python {{ name }} </h2>
    </html>
```

**NOTE: When you use render_template(), the HTML file you mention inside should be in ./templates/  in our case it should be ./templates/index.html**

Comment: Thanks that was one of the methods I found; it looks the most simple! 
Thanks Alot

Comment: if it has worked for you, can you accept it as the answer? @Kurt

Comment: if there is any problem with the answer please do comment, so that i could learn what my mistake is . cheers

Comment: can you provide some more code?